# Equivalence relations, operator

Tags: propositional-calculus, relations, equivalence-relations

> $\def\op{\mathbin{\#}}\def\R{\mathbin R}$Original question:
>
> A logical operation between two propositions $p$ and $q$ is denoted as $p\op q$. It is only true when $p$ is true and $q$ is false; otherwise it is false.
>   Let $R$ be a relation on the set of ordered pairs of propositions, where
>   $R$ is defined as follows:
>
> $\bigl((a,b),(c,d)\bigr) ∈ R$, if and only if $(a \land b) \op (c \vee d)$ is true.
>
> Is R an equivalence relation?

For symmetric, the rule is $∀a,b ∈ B$ s.t. $a\R b$, $b\R a$ is true.

But when I do the relation, do I bring the operator (i.e. $\land$ and $\lor$) over also?

For example:

1) $(a \land b) \op (c \lor d) \to (c \lor d) \op (a \land b)$

2) $(a \land b) \op (c \lor d)  → (c \land d) \op (a \lor b)$

which is the correct way of representing?

Comment: The part that says "Original question" doesn't actually contain a question. Also, the title mentions equivalence relations, but the body doesn't. It seems that perhaps there's something missing at the end of the block quote where the question asks something like whether $R$ is an equivalence relation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (a) A relation $R$ on the set $B$, is symmetric if and only if $\forall a,b \in B$, if $\;a\, R\, b$ is true, then $b\,R\,a$ is true. $\def\op{\mathbin{\#}}$

Here the elements of $B$ are ordered pairs of propositions.

> $\bigl((a,b),(c,d)\bigr) \in R$, if and only if $(a \land b) \op (c \vee d)$ is true.

So you must show that $R$ is symmetric, you need to show that $(2)$, as you've written, holds. That is, you need to show that $$\forall (a, b) \in B,\;
[(a \land b) \op (c \lor d)] \rightarrow [(c \land d) \op (a \lor b)].$$

*Whether your relation is symmetric or not depends on the set on which the relation is defined.*  If it is defined on the set of *all* ordered pairs of *all* propositions, e.g., $(a, b)$, where $a, b\, \in \{\text{All possible propositions}\}$, then you should be able to easily find a pair of propositions that provides a counterexample to symmetry.

**Note**: that to determine whether $R$ is an *equivalence relation* on the set $B$ of pairs $(x, y)$, you need to also need to determine whether the relation is reflexive and transitive, as well as symmetric:

> (b) The relation $R$ on the set $B$ is reflexive if and only if for all $(a,b) \in B$, $(a \land b) \op (a \lor b)$ is true.
>
> (c) The relation $R$ is transitive if and only if for all $(a, b), (b, c), (c, d) \in B$, if $(a \land b) \op (b \lor c)$ and $(b \land c) \op (c \lor d)$ are both true, then $(a \land b) \op (c \lor d)$ is also true.

---

Note that for $\op$, as defined, $(p \op q) \iff (p \land \lnot q) \iff \lnot(p\rightarrow q)$.

Answer (score 1):

Way 2 is the correct way, of course.
Arguments of R are pairs of propositions, not the operations $\wedge$ and $\vee$ on that pairs.
So, R is not symmetric.